# Google still returns old Wordpress user name when I search for it

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, search-engine-indexing

I created a Wordpress website with a particular user name that I no longer use (I fully deleted the Wordpress user and created a new one). Yet when I run a Google search for the initial user name, my Wordpress site still comes up in the search results even though there are no longer any instances of the name in my site. Any ideas how I can get Google to stop indexing that particular piece of info?

Comment: How long has it been since you changed the name?

Comment: About a week...?

Comment: It will take a lot more time than that. Months in fact. Depending upon how fresh your site is, age, rank, etc. If you have a Webmaster Tools account and your site is fairly small, you can Fetch as Google for each page, though there are limits to this. Not highly recommended. Patience is recommended. It will happen.

Comment: Sorry but there is already dozens of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters regarding the removal of both domain and urls from Google's index.

Comment: I would actually neither like to remove a domain nor a URL -- that was not my question.